# Why does v4 fragment not have startActivity(Intent, Bundle)?

Tags: android, android-appcompat

The regular fragment has this method signature, but v4 doesn't. I guess I could do `getActivity().startActivity(Intent, Bundle)`, but I feel there must be a reason this was changed this way?

Comment: In time: downvoters should atleast say why it's downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

I got some drive by downvotes with no answer, so I'll post what I did for others. Not sure if it's ideal, but it works.

I have a base class that extends v4.Fragment and I re-added the missing methods.

```
abstract public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    public void startActivity(Intent intent, Bundle bundle) {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            getActivity().startActivity(intent, bundle);
        }
    }

    public void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode, Bundle bundle) {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode, bundle);
        }
    }
}
```